# How is it possible to review 1000 "Close votes" within less than 10 minutes?

Tags: discussion, review

Just by accident I stumbled upon a user profile and instantly noticed the high number of gold badges. When looking at the list of badges I wondered how it is possible to review 1,000 close votes within less than 10 minutes?

In total the user did 20,000+ close vote reviews and a whole bunch of other reviews within a few hours.

https://superuser.com/help/badges/156/steward?userid=364367

Comment: Chances are it was a new badge that was calculated and applied retroactively. The time is when the badge was given, not when the reviews were done.

Comment: "How is it possible" - It's not :)

Comment: Massive amounts of coffee. Enough to bend time itself

Comment: @Mokubai Sounds logiacal. The badges were awarded end of January 2021. So the Close vote badge could have been introduced around this date...!?

Comment: Fixer is just that good.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek You have found the answer! Very, very black coffee acts as a very, very black hole. Except that it also keeps you awake while bending spacetime.

Comment: You do need to confirm you are not Anish Kapoor tho

Answer (score 16, accepted):

On January 28, 2021 [it was announced](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360198/355310) that [emphasis mine]

> The Steward badge can now be earned multiple times for every 1,000 reviews in each queue. If you have already completed 2,000 or more reviews, **we will backfill any additional Steward badges that you have already earned. You can expect to see them accrue over the next few days.**

What you noticed is a result of these "next few days".

Before the change only the first 1,000 reviews in each review queue were rewarded, so one could get at most one Steward badge per queue. After the change we earn one badge per every 1,000 reviews in each queue. Past reviews were taken into account and additional badges were awarded around January 29, 2021.

It's true the user in question got multiple Steward badges in one day. The user had earned them over many years though.

AFAIK a regular user (i.e. not formally a moderator) can review 20 tasks a day per queue.